# Check all checkbox does not work

Tags: jquery

In the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/auXdC/)

**CODE:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkAll() {
    var checked = $("#checkAll").is(':checked');
    $(".check_row").attr("checked", checked);
}
</script>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" onclick="checkAll()" />Check All <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="check_row" />One <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="check_row" />Two <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="check_row" />Three <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="check_row" />Four <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="check_row" />Five <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="check_row" />Six <br />    
</div>
```

"check all" checkbox works for only first time. Can someone help me to find out what is wrong happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
$(".check_row").attr("checked", checked);
```

to

```
$(".check_row").prop("checked", checked);
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/auXdC/8/)

Comment: You'd better do it more jQuery and HTML5 style: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/ZN5V4/)

Answer (score 2):

1. Since you are using jquery version greater then 1.6 not attribute are change from `attr` to `prop` in this
2. Don't declare the variable many time if you declare the variable in function it will be repeatedly declaring the variable many time
3. You don't even need the variable and if else conditions too... check my updated example

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/auXdC/6/)

```
var checked

function checkAll() {

    checked = $("#checkAll").is(':checked');

    $(".check_row").prop("checked", checked);

}
```

### Update

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/auXdC/12/)

```
$('#checkAll').on('change',function(){    
    $(".check_row").prop("checked", $(this).is(':checked'));    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#checkAll').on('change',function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $(".check_row").prop("checked", true);
    }
    else{
        $(".check_row").prop("checked", false);
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/auXdC/4/)

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
    $(".check_row").attr("checked", checked); 

     to

    $(".check_row").attr("checked", true);
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/auXdC/5/

Comment: Its working fine for me. Check again. When i click on the first checkbox(Check All), its checking all check boxes below.

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkAll() 
{
     var checked = $("#checkAll").is(':checked');

     $(".check_row").prop("checked", true);

    if(!checked)
    {
           $(".check_row").removeAttr("checked");
    }

}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hardiksondagar/auXdC/11/)